# divs scrolling underneath another once reached a point on page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 3 divs div1 div2 div3 on top of one another

I am trying to get div2 to stay fixed once the top of it is reached after scrolling past div1 while scrolling, and then div3 to scroll under it

I am using html, css, javascript for this, no jquery.

I was trying to tweak with this.

```
 window.onscroll = function() {
  var scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
  if (scrollTop >= document.getElementById("div1").offsetTop ) {
    document.getElementById("div3").style.position = "relative";
    document.getElementById("div2").style.marginTop = " 70px";
    document.getElementById("div3").style.marginTop = "- 50px";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("div3").style.position = "static";
    document.getElementById("div2").style.marginTop = "0px";
    document.getElementById("div3").style.marginTop = "0px";
  }
}
```

Now I am trying this:
  var objDiv = document.getElementById("div2");
    objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;

```
window.onscroll = function() {
var scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
if (scrollTop >=  div2 ) { 
  document.getElementById("copername").style.zIndex = "1"; 
  document.getElementById("copername").style.position = "fixed";
```

Comment: Could you share your HTML, maybe in a Fiddle, so we can see what the DOM looks like?

Comment: thnks but its very big, but basically it's just 3 divs one after the other

Comment: Someone is willing to help you solve YOUR problem, FOR FREE, and you comeback with "how hard it is to imagine...". Harder than "not having to imagine". Since it is easy for others to imagine, should not be hard for you to create an example.

Comment: @Ernesto lol, true,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing is probably to use JS to add/remove a `.sticky` class triggered by scrolling past the `offsetHeight` of `div1`:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
  var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  if (scrollTop > document.getElementById("div1").offsetHeight ) {
    document.getElementById("div2").classList.add('sticky');
    document.getElementById("div3").style.marginTop = "600px";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("div2").classList.remove('sticky');
    document.getElementById("div3").style.marginTop = "0px";
  }
}
```

You will also need to make sure your last `#div3` has a higher z-index and absolute positioning in your CSS:

```
#div3 {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Demo: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yocvLjao/3/)

Comment: thanks, however for some reason its not working, but iam looking for the solution

Comment: Did you compare to the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yocvLjao/3/) I provided?  Seems to be working for me.

Comment: thanks, iam still looking perhaps the error is on my side,  brb

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this. Which I think achieves the result you are looking for.

You can subtract the `window.pageYOffset` from the `.offsetTop` of div2. This is set before the scroll function begins. Test if this expression is less than zero apply the following css stylings via JS:

```
div2.style.position = 'fixed'
div2.style.top = '0'; 
div3.style.position = 'absolute'
div3.style.zIndex = "-1";
return div3.style.marginTop = div2Height + "px";
```

Otherwise apply this styling.

```
div2.style.position = 'relative'
div3.style.position = 'relative'
return div3.style.marginTop = 0;
```

```js
var div2 =   document.getElementById('div2'),
    div2Pos = document.getElementById('div2').offsetTop,
    div2Height = document.getElementById('div2').offsetHeight,
    div3 = document.getElementById('div3');

document.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  var windowPos = window.pageYOffset;

  if ((div2Pos-windowPos) < 0){
    div2.style.position = 'fixed'
    div2.style.top = '0'; 
    div3.style.position = 'absolute'
    div3.style.zIndex = "-1";
    return div3.style.marginTop = div2Height + "px";  
  }

  div2.style.position = 'relative'
  div3.style.position = 'relative'
  return div3.style.marginTop = 0;
});
```

```css
div{
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
}

#div1{
  background: skyblue;
}

#div2{
  background: darkgrey;
}

#div3{
  background: steelblue;
  color: white;
  height: 3000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"><h1>Content</h1></div>
<div id="div2"><h1>Other Content</h1></div>
<div id="div3"><h1> Some more Content</h1></div>
```

Comment: thank you iam trying to apply it to my case, and will brb in a min